# Problem with my VB2005-MSAccess Connection

Tags: vb.net

I am using MS Access as a database, but the error occurs in column Abstract.

Error message:

> Column 'Abstract' does not belong to table tblBooks

This column is actually included in the table but I'm not sure if the problem is its DataType.(Memo)

Is it possible to use this field with Memo datatype? Is there any error with my code (using my module)?

My code:

```
Module Module1
    Public MyConn As New OdbcConnection("Dsn=MS Access Database;dbq=D:\MyPrograms\VB.Net\Library System\dblibrary.mdb;defaultdir=D:\MyPrograms\VB.Net\Library System;driverid=25;fil=MS Access;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;uid=admin")
    Public MyComm As New OdbcCommand
    Public MyTable As New DataSet
    Public MyAdapt As New OdbcDataAdapter
    Public Counter As Integer

    Function Adapt(ByVal MyCommand As String, ByVal MyDataSet As String) As String
        MyAdapt = New OdbcDataAdapter(MyCommand, MyConn)
        MyAdapt.Fill(MyTable, MyDataSet)
        Return 0
    End Function
End Module



Private Sub Search()

     If cmbCategoryFilter.SelectedItem = "All" Then
        Adapt("select * from tblBooks", "tblBooks")
        txtISBNInfo.Text = MyTable.Tables(0).Rows(Counter)("ISBN").ToString
        txtTitleInfo.Text = MyTable.Tables(0).Rows(Counter)("Title").ToString
        txtAuthorInfo.Text = MyTable.Tables(0).Rows(Counter)("Author").ToString
        txtAbstractInfo.Text = MyTable.Tables(0).Rows(Counter)("Abstract").ToString
     End If

End Sub
```

Comment: **Column 'Abstract' does not belong to table tblBooks.** Actually, that column is included in my tblBooks with datatype `Memo`... kndly help me...

Comment: try changing the field name. Sometimes field names conflict with sql or .net data types